# Low Latency Audio Output C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, low-latency

I am currently working on a project, wherein I am supposed to process frames. The task at hand is to read the frame data, detect if the data crosses a particular threshold and then make a sound.

The frame per second is about 45-50.

I did that with the function Beep () and tried 2 ms for the duration but then the beeps were in a queue. It still takes for a while even though the input does not have values ​​above the threshold. So I just made a delay of 175ms and then it worked fine, but now I'm just processing 5 samples per second out of the 45-50 samples.

Now I'm using the function PlaySound() and playing a 1ms sound file in the player. Now it takes about 250 ms to play the sound. So now even without delay 4 samples.

I am completely new to real-time programming like this. I am facing the Latency issue.

I would really appreciate it if any of you can help me with the project.

Thank you in advance.

OS:- Windows 10
IDE:- Visual Studio 2017 Community
Language:- C++

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In order to help you we need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code and a specific question with respect to that code you'd like addressing.

Comment: Play the sound on a background thread.

Comment: If you want to stay with Windows (not the best choice for low-latency computing), have a look into DirectSound (used to be part of DirectX SDK).

Comment: You havent really got a question here. At least not a specific one. I suggest rephrasing it to a more specific request. "Why doesnt this code pasted below work?" types of things. Click around and read other threads for good examples of how to set up a question in a way that maximizes your chance of a successful reply outcome.

Best I can suggest at this level of vagueness is to look into existing audio frameworks. Don't reinvent the wheel, so to speak. For low latency on windows, Steingergs ASIO is the defacto standard